# Automated way of generating logs

Tags: android, logging, generator

is there a way to generate logs (writing them automatically) in the Android code? (I'm using Android Studio). I was thinking of some code generator or anything like that. I'm new to the code at work and I'd like to generate logs for all activities and views.

Thanks a lot
Cristian

Comment: What does "generate logs for all activities and views" mean? What exactly are you looking to log? Where are you looking to log it?

Comment: If you mean check when each method is called and variable values, you can use Live Templates and make it manually, it's not time consuming, create your own Live Template that fits you or use logd, logm, logr and specify its content.

Comment: What are you trying to automate? Isn't `Log.x(...);` enough?

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Sorry, it was kind of vague. I was thinking about a way to add the logs without having to go through all activities (and presenters) and add the Log.d() calls manually. There are many dozens of activities, that's why I don't want to do this by hand. Plus, I might have to add this for several code branches. I was thinking about adding logs onCreate() for activities and in constructors for presenters.